# Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing - Jenkins pipeline Xcode Test cases failing

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

```
Destination simulator is: platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s Plus,OS=12.4
Excluded paths from coverage are: .*Tests.*
Creating directory sonar-reports/
Running tests
+ xcodebuild test -workspace Project.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectTests -configuration Debug -enableCodeCoverage YES -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s Plus,OS=12.4' -destination-timeout 60
2019-10-17 13:25:05.905 xcodebuild[5811:47314]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:
/Users/XXUSERXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-gcyoajxbeybhskdjmpfudvsghpth/Logs/Test/Test-ProjectTests-2019.10.17_13-20-39-+0530.xcresult/1_Test/Diagnostics/ProjectTests-3CAB9DB7-C238-45F1-984F-C3C061536B14/ProjectTests-674B5C61-8938-4243-BEE2-66691C2F4489/Session-ProjectTests-2019-10-17_132505-kBU2rX.log

2019-10-17 13:25:05.907 xcodebuild[5811:47306] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (340B3860-B575-4819-A2D6-C529266893C8) Beginning test session ProjectTests-340B3860-B575-4819-A2D6-C529266893C8 at 2019-10-17 13:25:05.906 with Xcode 10G8 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7f8b11877220> {
        SimDevice: iPhone 6s Plus (CE03A4E0-9AD3-4BB4-8146-AE5C1288ABC3, iOS 12.4, Shutdown)
} (12.4 (16G73))

2019-10-17 13:25:28.196 xcodebuild[5811:47306] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (340B3860-B575-4819-A2D6-C529266893C8) 

Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing
```

I've been facing above error message since last week, I'm using Jenkins pipeline to build Xcode and then run the test cases for Sonar report with Xcode 12.3 MAC OS Catalina.

I even tried to run in different machines but getting different error messages, fastlane is not installed in the current system also not included in the script file.
After waiting about 30 - 40 minutes I've got the following screen which shows that the Test cases are failed.

```
2019-10-17 13:25:28.196 xcodebuild[5811:47306] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (340B3860-B575-4819-A2D6-C529266893C8) Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing.
2019-10-17 13:43:38.360 xcodebuild[5811:47306] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 1112.476 elapsed -- Testing started completed.
2019-10-17 13:43:38.361 xcodebuild[5811:47306] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.001 sec, +0.001 sec -- start
2019-10-17 13:43:38.361 xcodebuild[5811:47306] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 1112.476 sec, +1112.474 sec -- end

Failing tests:
    ProjectTests:
        *******ModelTests.testCreate****Details()
        *******ModelTests.testCreate****Details()

Test session results and logs:
    /Users/XXUSERXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-gcyoajxbeybhskdjmpfudvsghpth/Logs/Test/Test-ProjectTests-2019.10.17_13-20-39-+0530.xcresult

** TEST FAILED **

+ returnValue=65
+ set +x
ERROR - Command 'xcodebuild test -workspace Project.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectTests -configuration Debug -enableCodeCoverage YES -destination platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s Plus,OS=12.4 -destination-timeout 60' failed with error code: 65
```

Test cases are working locally when ran in the current system, but failing when running via Jenkins pipeline for Sonar Testing.

Thanks

Comment: did you find solution?